# Laravel 5.4 - Access date on a multiple levels of hasMany / hasOne relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I got stuck on access data on a multiple level of relationship on Laravel 5.4.  I have a feeling that it is straight forward in Laravel but I just can't figure it out.  Here is the setup:

I got 3 models: User/Post/Application - representing user come to the job site to apply on the job posts.

I have the login set up and want to allow user to view application they been sent to the related job posts:

```
public function index() {

    $user = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
    $applications = $user->appliedPosts;

    return view('pages.user.appliedPost.index')->withApplications($applications);

}
```

I am able to connect the user with applications, but how do I get the title of the post based on the post_id on the "applications" table?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show User/Post/Application table structure??

Comment: Maybe I'm assuming to much about your model structure, but isn't it simply `$applications->each(function ($application) { $application->post->title });`? This assumes that your `Application` model has a belongsTo relationship `post` to `Post` model, which holds the `title` attribute you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if the `applications` are related to the `post` you can access the post title just like this:

```
$application->post->title
```